# Go gin validate by anonymous struct

Tags: go, go-gin

is it possible to do validation via anonymous stucture?
The problem is that it is impossible to do it through a specific type, because there are many drivers inside and I would not like to make a separate function for each of them, but pass their validation through a common function.
Example of code

```
func CreatePayment(context *gin.Context) {
    input := paymentpackage.GetValidation()

    if err := context.ShouldBindBodyWith(&input, binding.JSON); err != nil {
        context.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{"success": false, "errors": err.Error()})
        return
    }
}


// payment package
func GetValidation() any {
    return driverpackage.GetValidation()
}

// driver package
func GetValidation() any {
    type Validator struct {
        Key      string `json:"api_key" binding:"required"`
        Password string `json:"api_password" binding:"required"`
        Currency string `json:"api_currency" binding:"required,coinremitterCurrency"`
    }
    return Validator{}
}
```

Comment: Note that to successfully bind the request to some value, the argument's _dynamic type_ must be a pointer, the static type doesn't have to be. I.e. if `input`'s static type is `any` then `&input` is unnecessary (if not outright wrong), passing `input` as is, is enough. On the other hand, if the dynamic type is a struct type, e.g. `Validator`, and not a pointer to a struct type, e.g. `*Validator`, then the binding will not work. In other words, your `GetValidation` should have `return &Validator{}` and your `CreatePayment` should have `ShouldBindBodyWith(input, ...)`.

Comment: thx, this works:)